# Button Effects in tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have the following code below:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=20, height=50)
buttonBG1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 20, 50, outline="")
buttonTXT1 = canvas.create_text((10, 25), text="Press Me", angle='90', font=("Calibri", 8))
canvas.tag_bind(buttonBG1, "<ButtonPress-1>")
canvas.tag_bind(buttonTXT1, "<ButtonRelease-1>", press) # press is the command function 
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

My question is concerning how to add effect to the button (with no outline) i am creating. I know that i can add through:

.configure(relief="sunken")

.configure(relief="raised")

However when i add it in this way to my code it is not working:

```
canvas.configure(relief="sunken")
canvas.configure(relief="raised")
```

It is not giving any error but it is not giving and effect like it should. What is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not wrong but, by default, the canvas's border width is 0 so the relief effects are invisible. To be able to see them, you need to set the border width to at least 1.

In the example below I also use the `activefill` option of the rectangle to highlight it when the cursor is over it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def press(event):
    # make relief effect button is pressed
    canvas.config(relief='sunken')

def release(event):
    # remove relief when button is no longer pressed
    canvas.config(relief='flat')  

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=20, height=50, borderwidth=1)
buttonBG1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 20, 50, outline="", activefill='#F1F1F1')  # highlight rectangle when active
buttonTXT1 = canvas.create_text((10, 25), text="Press Me", angle='90', font=("Calibri", 8))
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", press)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When i added a borderwidth it still didn't give me effects. Moreoverr,i don't want any outlines on my canvas and borderwidth gives me an outline effect

Comment: Ok, then why are you trying to change the relief if you don't want to see the border (relief is just an visual effect due to the color chosen for the border)? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to add the sunken and raised effect to see that i pressed the button however, originally i don't want to see the border of the button unless pressed.